# cannot access website from within my network

Tags: connection-timeout

A website prodecotech.com is hosted by Bluehost

Out of the blue last week my entire office could not access prodecotech.com the connection would time out.

However this is only the situation from one of our internet connections. If I switch over to a guest connection, or use a mobile connection, the website loads fine. The website also loads perfectly fine for ATT and BlueHost tech support.

Our network is configured as follows.
We have a 50MB Dedicated Fiber Connection from an ATT Managed Router. The managed router has 2 ports in use. 1 Port going to OUR router for Data traffic and 1 Port going to OUR switch for VOIP Traffic.

If I connect a laptop to OUR router managing data traffic and try to access prodecotech.com, I get the same results, the connection times out.

If I connect a laptop to the switch managing VOIP traffic, prodecotech.com loads fine.

If I use our guest wifi which is through Comcast, the website loads fine as well.

So the problem is isolated to the Data Portion of my network.

There has been no configuration changes on our router or the managed ATT router.

I thought perhaps somehow our IP got blacklisted by BlueHost, but BlueHost says this is not the case.

ATT support is able to reach the website through their managed router.

I'm utterly stumped.

Additionally, I also cannot access the FTP or CPANEL Server Status for this hosting, both time out as well.

TRACERT has been giving me the following results consistently:

[image: cmd: tracert prodecotech.com]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does a direct PING work? I can both ping and traceroute to 162.144.177.240 from where I am. Also, make sure you haven't defined a proxy or anything for 162.144.177.240 for testing purposes or anything.

Comment: a PING command issues the same result it just times out on the DATA portion (ATT FIBER) of our network but works through the VOIP portion(ATT FIBER) and the GUEST portion(COMCAST SHARED).

Since it works through one segment of our ATT FIBER and not the other segment this leads me to believe the issue is between our workstations and the ATT MANAGER ROUTER.

The organization is as follows:

WORKSTATION --> 48 PORT SWITCH --> DUAL WAN ROUTER --> ATT MANAGED ROUTER

Comment: I'd check the routing tables on both routers and on your machine ("netstat -rn" is the Unix command). I'd bet quatloos that you created a special route for 162.144.177.240 and forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to the wrong MTU(maximum transmission unit) in the router's network configuration. When I changed MTU to 1452 it started working fine.

You should contact your service provider and ask for appropriate configuration settings.